# How do I make a List within a list in it in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Lets assume I have a MySql table:

`Number  |  Squared`

`2       |     4`

`3       |     9`

`4       |     16`

`5       |     25`

In my Java application, this is what I have so far:

```
List<Integer> finalList = fetchStuff();
log.info(desiredList);

private List<Integer> fetchStuff() {
  List<Integer> listToReturn = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<NameOfClass> desiredList = desiredListRepo.findAll();
  for (NameOfClass nameOfClass : desiredList) {
       listToReturn.add(nameOfClass.getNumber());
       listToReturn.add(nameOfClass.getSquaredNumber());
  }
  return listToReturn;
}
```

When I print desiredList, this is the output that I want to see:
`[[2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25]]`
But currently, I'm seeing:
`[2,4,3,9,4,16,5,25]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data type is wrong. The title even says "List within a list", yet nothing like that is happening in the code. `listToReturn` needs to be a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<Integer>` is a `List` of `Integer`s. You want a `List<List<Integer>>`, a list of lists of integers. This works like the following:

```java
List<List<Integer>> finalList = fetchStuff();
log.info(desiredList);

private List<List<Integer>> fetchStuff() {
  List<List<Integer>> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
  List<NameOfClass> desiredList = desiredListRepo.findAll();
  for (NameOfClass nameOfClass : desiredList) {
       List<Integer> inner=new ArrayList<>();
       inner.add(nameOfClass.getNumber());
       inner.add(nameOfClass.getSquaredNumber());
       listToReturn.add(inner);
  }
  return listToReturn;
}
```

If you want to have a `List` of pairs of numbers, you can use `Map.Entry`:

```java
List<Map.Entry<Integer>> finalList = fetchStuff();
log.info(desiredList);

private List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> fetchStuff() {
  List<Map.Entry<Integer>> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
  List<NameOfClass> desiredList = desiredListRepo.findAll();
  for (NameOfClass nameOfClass : desiredList) {
       inner.add(nameOfClass.getNumber());
       inner.add(nameOfClass.getSquaredNumber());
       listToReturn.add(Map.entry(desiredList.getNumber(), desiredList. getSquaredNumber()));
  }
  return listToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my question, I've edited it. Can you edit your answer accordingly, please? Also, what does it mean when you say `"List<Integer> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>(); ` Is this a List of Type Integer or is this an Arraylist?

Comment: An `ArrayList` is a `List` so it is a `List` of `Integer`s and an `ArrayList` of `Integer`s.

Comment: Got it! Also, when I try your approach, I am getting the `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<Integer>> to List<Integer>`. I think this is because I have it as `private List<Integer>` . Should I change that as well to `private List<List<Integer>>`? Thanks for answering!

Comment: And also, the `desiredList` is also initialized as `List<Integer>`. Should that also be changed? Can you edit your answer again, please?

Comment: My fault, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Can you also change the type of `desiredList` in your answer so I can approve it! thanks for not being condescending-I'm learning! :)

Comment: Why should the type of `desiredList` be changed? The repository doesn't seem to return a list of lists and my code also doesn't require that.

Comment: It gives me the same error over there at `fetchStuff()` too that `Type Mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<Integer>> to List<Integer>`

Comment: Yeah, I added that.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question again. I had accidentally defined 2 `desiredList`. I meant can you change the type of `finalList` to `List<List<Integer>>`?

Comment: I changed that, too.